# Proving from first principles that if $0\lt x\lt x'\lt x+1$ then $2x(x'-x)\lt x'^2-x^2\lt 2(x+1)(x'-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, axioms

Stuck on this analysis question...

Prove from first principles that for all real numbers $x,x'$ with $0\lt x\lt x'\lt x+1$:

$$2x(x'-x)\lt x'^2-x^2\lt 2(x+1)(x'-x)$$

I've solved the first order diff equation on the right hand side to get x=-1 and x=c1 e^x but I'm not sure if this was helpful or where to go from there...

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Using the simplest approach, one can refine this to $$2x(x'-x)\lt x'^2-x^2\lt (2x+1)(x'-x)$$

Comment: Hmmm... and $x'$ is not related to any derivative here hence there is no "first order diff equation on the right hand side".

Comment: What "differential equation" did you solve? You say that $x'$ is just a number, so where are the derivatives in the inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^2$. Then

$(x')^2-x^2=f(x')-f(x)=f'(z)(x'-x)$ with some $z \in (x,x').$

(Mean value theorem).

Then we have $2x <2z < 2x' <2(x+1)$,  hence $2x <f'(z)<2(x+1).$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the left inequality as: $(2x - (x'+x))(x'-x) = -(x-x')^2 <0$ which is clear since $x \ne x'$, and the right one: $(x'-x)(x'+x - 2x - 2)=(x'-x)(x'-x-2)< 0$ which is clear since $x' - x > 0, x'-x <1 < 2 \implies x'-x - 2 < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x(x'-x)\lt x'^2-x^2\lt 2(x+1)(x'-x)$$
Since $x'-x>0$ 
$$2x\lt x'+x\lt 2(x+1)$$

$$x\lt x'\lt x+2$$

Which is true since it's true for $x+1$ on the right

Answer (score 0):

You even have a tighter result:
$$2x(x'-x)<x'^2-x^2<(2x+1)(x'-x).$$
Indeed rewrite $x'^2-x^2$ as
$$(x'-x)(x'+x)=(x'-x)\bigl(2x+(x'-x)\bigr),$$
and use the hypothesis that $0<x'-x<1$.